# Точка соприкосновения двух отрезков

Tags: геометрия, lisp, autocad

Здравствуйте. 
Нужно найти точку, которая расположена на расстоянии a от точки A и от точки B на расстоянии b.

Я так понял, что нужно сначала ввести данные(A, a, B, b). Только вот что дальше делать - не знаю.

Я пока только начал. Написал ввод данных

```
(defun fnc()
  (setq A (getpoint "Enter A(dot):"))
  (setq a (getdist A "Enter a(dist):"))
  (setq B (getpoint "Enter B(dot):"))
  (setq b (getpoint B "Enter b(dist):"))
  )
```

Может кто подскажет, что дальше делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такс, вроде решил задачку. Я вывожу только одну точку, т.к. это по заданию.
Решил по [этому](http://algolist.manual.ru/maths/geom/intersect/circlecircle2d.php) методу.

```
(defun fnc()
  (setq A (getpoint "\nEnter A(dot):"))(princ A)
  (setq ah (getdist A "\nEnter a(dist):"))(princ ah)
  (command "_circle" (list (car A)(cadr A)) ah)
  ; Для удобства нарисуем окружности
  (setq B (getpoint "\nEnter B(dot):"))(princ B)
  (setq bh (getdist B "\nEnter b(dist):"))(princ bh)
  (command "_circle" (list (car B)(cadr B)) bh)
  ; Определим флаг
  (setq s -1)
  ; Вычислим расстояние между центрами окружностей
  (setq d (expt (+ (expt (- (car B) (car A)) 2) (expt (- (cadr B) (cadr A)) 2)) 0.5))
  (if (> d (+ ah bh))
    (progn
      (print "Решений ноль. Окружности не пересекаются")
      (setq s 0)))
  (if (< d (- ah bh))
    (progn
      (print "Решений ноль. Одна окружность внутри второй")
      (setq s 0)))
  ; если решение есть, то...
  (if (not (= s 0))
    (progn
      (setq aa (/ (+ (- (expt ah 2) (expt bh 2)) (expt d 2)) (* 2.0 d)))
      (setq h (expt (- (expt ah 2) (expt aa 2)) 0.5))
      ; Вычислим точку
      (setq x2 (+ (car A)  (/ (* aa (- (car B) (car A))) d)))
      (setq y2 (+ (cadr A) (/ (* aa (- (cadr B) (cadr A))) d)))

      (setq x3 (+ x2 (/ (* h (- (cadr B) (cadr A))) d)))
      (setq y3 (+ y2 (- (/ (* h (- (car B) (car A))) d))))
      (print "X = ")(princ x3)
      (print "Y = ")(princ y3)

      (command "_circle" (list x3 y3) 0.5)))

  )
```

Код сыроват, но работает.
Может быть, кому-то понадобится.

Answer (score 1):

По своей сути задача сводится к нахождению точек пересечения двух окружностей: с центром в точке `A` и радиусом `a` и с центром в точке `B` и радиусом `b`. Таких точек может быть 0, 1 или 2.

Необходимую для решения математику можно найти [здесь](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/circles_intersection) или [здесь](http://algolist.manual.ru/maths/geom/intersect/circlecircle2d.php).

Comment: Глупый вопрос, конечно, но как из переменной, присвоенной через getpoint взять отдельно значения x и y?

Comment: Честно говоря, я первый раз сталкиваюсь с AutoLISP, зато я хорошо гуглю. Там, на самом деле, может быть три координаты. Документация: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-AutoLISP/files/GUID-BFED8707-AB01-49BC-B0A9-D872794311DF-htm.html

Comment: Да я и сам совсем недолго в Autolisp, заставляют в универе учить. Насчет вашей ссылки. Там есть только вариант list, а мне нужно от getpoint, так, как точку надо вводить в интерактивном режиме. Там на самом деле три координаты при вводе через getpoint образуется (x y z), но вывести x/y никак отдельно не могу.

Comment: Это же Lisp, там всё - списки, в том числе и результат функции ```getpoint```. По ссылке есть информация, как получить ```X```, ```Y``` и ```Z``` компоненты.

Comment: Ох, я понял. В AutoLisp регистр переменных не важен. Элементарно. Ох уж эти привычки из C-подобных языков. У меня просто перезаписывалась переменная. Теперь могу сосредоточиться на решении задачи.